# gjs strange process when alt tab

Tags: gnome, wayland, pop-os, window-switching

I'm using POP OS 21.04 with default gnome desktop enviroment (Gnome with Wayland) I noticed that when I use the alt-tab shortcut a strange process appears called "gjs" (this only happens on Wayland)

When i use the command:  ps aux | grep gjs I get the following output:

```
kiriaevi    3023  0.0  0.4 2744968 29028 ?       Sl   20:56   0:00 /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Notifications
kiriaevi    6165  0.0  1.0 2799156 71668 ?       Sl   21:24   0:00 gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/ding.js -E -P /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com -M 0 -D 0:0:1920:1080:1
kiriaevi    6674  0.0  0.0  18924   912 pts/0    S+   21:34   0:00 grep --color=auto gjs
```

I don't think it's a process that should be deleted, can I at least hide this process from the alt+tab menu?

Thanks in advance for all the answers!

Comment: ` ps aux | grep gjs | grep -v grep` would omit the ps command from the listing.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're using Wayland.

To get rid of it, go the the "Extensions" application that comes installed with POP_OS, then disable "Desktop Icons NG (DING)". You won't see `gjs` in the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut anymore.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Was ruining my alt-tab workflow.