# Disable mouse scaling when fractional scaling is enabled in Ubuntu/Gnome/PopOS

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, display, multi-monitor, pop-os

I'm running PopOS (Gnome Desktop & Ubuntu based). I've configured my 2nd monitor to run at 200% scale using Fractional Scaling. This works great for the display!

The problem is that the mouse cursor is also being scaled on the external monitor. When the mouse cursor gets scaled it also gets laggy. The mouse is perfectly responsive on my primary display where it's not scaled.

Is there a way to disable the mouse scaling on the external monitor while keeping the display at fractional scaling?

Comment: Using X11 backend ? As far as I understand there would be some Xorg problem involved. I suggest you move to wayland backend claimed offering much better support and in particular no mouse lags when fractional scaling is active (never tried though).

Comment: I'm working on getting wayland backend running. Following two threads on that front: https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/vliibb/is_wayland_backend_an_option_in_popos/idw7icl/?context=3 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700938/enable-wayland-in-popos-22-04

Comment: @MC68020 I finally got Wayland backend working and it has fixed the lag problem. If you would post that comment as an answer I'll happily accept it. Unfortunately the Wayland backend introduced another issue, so trade one for the other, but your suggestion was really valuable all the same.

Answer (score 3):

After following the advice of @MC68020 and getting Wayland backend working with PopOS I stumbled upon the solution without needing to run Wayland.

```
sudo kernelstub -a "nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
```

Reboot after applying. Validate with `sudo kernelstub -p`

Based on this [long discussion thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/vliibb/is_wayland_backend_an_option_in_popos/idw7icl/?context=3) I applied the above line as part of trying to get Wayland working. That did indeed get Wayland backend working, but Wayland had another show-stopper issue as discussed in that thread.

When I returned to Xorg, however, the mouse lag had vanished. The only change I can reasonably attribute to the solution is the kernel boot option above.

Comment: Congrats David !

Comment: Seems to be working! Thanks David!

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/mind-overflow/gnome-fs-duplicate-cursor-fix to fix your issue; it sounds like it could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I'll try this after I test the Wayland backend suggestion fully (getting that enabled is turning out to be a challenge). I don't have the duplicate cursor bug though, and the fact that this is unmaintained makes me a bit nervous.

Comment: FYI, I later tried to install this and failed. The repo is long since unsupported and appears to no longer work with the current version. But it's a useful reference here nonetheless.