# Pop os brightness stuck at maximum

Tags: nvidia, display, pop-os, brightness, backlight

So I've encountered this problem every time I installed linux on my laptop. I've asked it before [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368249/display-brightness-problem), but that didn't go well.

Now I'v installed Pop OS (22.04) and I'm fully committed to it, it's not dual boot anymore and it's the only OS I currently run. I did try gaming on it and works just fine, I actually have no problem right now with it, except the brightness of course xd

The situation: Brightness of the screen is stuck at maximum (I think, it's really bright), the `actual_brightness` file has 100 in it, the brightness slider changes the `brightness` file (both files on `/sys/class/backlight/nvidia_0`). 
I CAN change the brightness using `xrandr --output DP-2 --brightness 0.5` for example, but it won't stay that way and none of the files I mentioned change when I use `xrandr`.
Also, the keyboard backlight works just fine, I didn't install any RGB related software and it has the default red color but the brightness level is working perfect. Changing the brightness of the keyboard backlight will return the display brightness to maximum, if I've used `xrandr` before and changed it.

What I have done:
I did dual boot Pop OS before wiping windows from the laptop, and in dual boot mode, I've changed the permissions of `brightness` and `actual_brightness` files (`chmod 777`), and also tried to manually write numbers in them but it didn't work (Used nano and vim for it, in `sudo` mode). I've searched for solutions but couldn't find working ones. There were somethings about older versions of nvidia drivers solving these problems, but:

1. I need up to date drivers, because I game on it and can't keep an outdated driver for gaming. Basically everything I need to install (steam, wine, lutris) will update the drivers or need up to date drivers.
2. This problem is not new, I had it every single time I've installed linux on this laptop (multiple times Ubuntu, I think I did manjaro one time and probably Pop OS before), and I think it's something related to how my hardware interacts with linux or something.

My specs: ASUS ROG GL503VS, Intel Corei7-7700HQ, Nvidia Geforce GTX 1070 (The only GPU on my laptop, and it is dedicated of course), 1920x1080 144hz GeSync capable display (I don't know if it helps at all). 
Software: Pop OS 22.04, `nvidia-smi` output:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Mon Nov 20 16:50:39 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 545.29.02              Driver Version: 545.29.02    CUDA Version: 12.3     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   60C    P0              35W / 115W |    380MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2130      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          139MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2234      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         57MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5027      G   ...RunOnOsLogin,WebAssemblyTrapHandler       88MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5593      G   ...,WinRetrieveSuggestionsOnlyOnDemand       90MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And `uname -r` output:

```
$ uname -r
6.5.6-76060506-generic
```

If any other information is needed, I can happily give it to you. I'm quite new to linux (despite many tries) and know a thing or two but not much at all. I really want to use it as my main OS, but I think I'm gonna lose my eyes in the process if I can't solve this problem XD. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I've found [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules/issues/573#issuecomment-1804213566) and I'd be very, VERY unlucky if I installed linux exactly every time there was a bug regarding the brightness. I'll keep this question open, wait for the update and see if it solves it. I hop it comes sooner rather than later, I'm on proprietary version and can't apply the patch xd. Will update when the driver update comes. Until then, `xrandr` it is...

Comment: Note: You have both an Intel iGPU (in the CPU) and the dGPU Nvidia. You can select one or the other with Nvidia X Server Settings (select profile and reboot) unless the iGPU has been disabled in the firmware (unlikely). Does it occur the same way with both?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks for the comment. I can't see profile settings in the X server, can you point out where it must be exactly?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/858037/1210606

Comment: @ChanganAuto Well I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately it's another dead-end (or I'm confusing things again xd). I don't have `nvidia-prime` and I can't install it, because apparently pop os already has one ([this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/avbdcq/do_not_install_nvidia_prime/)). After using `system76-power`:
```$ system76-power graphics hybrid
setting graphics to hybrid
daemon returned an error message: "does not have switchable graphics"```

Comment: The link was meant to show the the profiles picture only, I should have made that clear. From your results we can infer the iGPU is disabled in UEFI, either "permanently", a vendor's decision, or there's a setting to re-enable it. In any case it was just to try something. Even if worked with the Intel GPU it wouldn't say much, if anything, about why it doesn't with the Nvidia. Your own link seems to provide a temporary patch.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ah, good to know, maybe I'll try to dig it up in bios settings. Thanks so much anyways, and yeah I hope the patch is coming soon. A side note though, does `xrandr` actually change the backlight the way it is handled in windows? For some reason I think that even at like 0.2 or 0.1, the backlight is still higher than it should be, and `xrandr` changes color or something. at 0, the black screen has considerable backlight to it, but I can't compare it to windows.

Comment: I don't use `xrandr` regularly and never for such thing. But nice you mentioned it again. If it works in some capacity that means POP_OS is running with X11. You may try to enable the new wayland - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700938/enable-wayland-in-popos-22-04 - and test if the normal keys work there or not. POP_OS should be enabling wayland by default now but apparently it isn't.

Comment: @ChanganAuto the `WaylandEnable=false` was uncommented in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and I set it to true, wayland was enabled and the monitor name was changed afterwards. `xrandr` wouldn't work anymore (used the new name of course), and other things were mostly the same. nvidia X server had less settings thuogh. Brightness keys on keyboard show on screen brightness bar changes but wouldn't change the actual brightness of the screen. Keyboard backlight was still working fine.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you so much again, this problem is kinda driving me crazy and anything to try really helps even if it doesn't work. I'm waiting for the driver update and will update this question for future visitors. I may consider switching over to open nvidia drivers, I have to see if it has more problems or not.

Comment: Just wanted to say I'm also having the exact same issue. Exact same kernel version, and exact same Nvidia driver version. Thanks for documenting this. This helped me understand what the problem was. Hopefully Pop OS gets the newer driver into their repositories soon.

Comment: As a work around, I found this suggestion to work: https://github.com/pop-os/nvidia-graphics-drivers/issues/195#issuecomment-1819004721
I had to switch from "Discrete Graphics" in BIOS to "Dynamic Graphics" in BIOS. I would like to switch back eventually because I believe my system sometimes freezes before reaching the login screen if I have "Dynamic Graphics" enabled.

Comment: @retodaredevil Thanks for the comments. I checked and the option to change graphics mode was not in my bios settings, and I don't remember noticing anything about integrated graphics card regarding my laptop. It is there apparently, but at least the option is not there. Recently they made a new pull request in the repo I linked, and It's waiting for approval. Let's hope it'll fix the problem :D

Comment: @retodaredevil The update is released just now to fix the bug, and people confirmed it fixes it. However, while I was testing it (before release), I still had the problem. Can you check it to see if it fixes the problem for you? I'm also updating it and report back here, hopefully with a proper answer or at least a work around that actually works for me xd

Comment: Yep! It fixes the problem for me. I changed my BIOS back to "Discrete Graphics" and everything seems to be like before. I am having a weird problem that occurs when I first boot into my desktop environment or wake my computer from sleep. If I have multiple monitors plugged in in this case, my computer will operate normally for a couple of seconds, and then freeze. These drivers do work great, though. It fixed another problem I was having were if the screen was not being updated for some time, it would glitch out (to be fair 545.29.02 fixed that issue, though)

Comment: @retodaredevil That's good to know, at least it's working for almost all people. I think I stumbled upon some threads about multi-monitor setups but I don't have one and I can't help you on that case xd. I'm gonna post an an answer here in case others find this question.

Comment: Yeah the monitor thing is pretty random, but it's on par for NVIDIA graphics support. One bug is fixed, another appears. It's not bothering me enough to gather enough info to report it as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

From the research that I've done, I've come to the conclusion that I can't do anything about it. Feel free to point out where and why I'm wrong, I'll be very grateful.

I've found out that Linux apparently uses the integrated graphics card by default for backlight control, and I couldn't find a way to change it. I know there are NVIDIA files in `/sys/class/backlight` and those brightness files are getting changed, but from [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=284359) (the post #4) it seems I need the igpu enabled. We'll get to the display connection later though.

I don't have an "Enable igpu" option in my bios, I've updated it to the latest one Asus has on their website for my laptop. And from [this](https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/rog-gaming-notebooks/integrated-graphics-and-missing-options-in-bios/m-p/563297/highlight/true#M129722) forum post, it seems like the igpu on my laptop is disabled by manufacturer. Which means I probably can't enable it at all.

I've dug a little deeper and I kinda got an answer for why the ipgu is disabled. My laptop has a G-Sync capable (apparently the term is important, I don't know) display, and for it to work, the display has to be directly connected to the dedicated gpu. I've checked and G-Sync is working in Linux for me. I don't have deep knowledge on this but these are all things that I could find on the internet.

But it begs the question that if my display is directly connected to my dedicated gpu, why I still need the igpu for the backlight to work? I don't have an answer for it and I hope the answer is "No I don't need it". But my google-fu and understanding of computer hardware are being pushed to their limits. Since I had this problem over the years and on multiple distros (I even installed Manjaro a few days ago as dual boot and although I didn't tinker with it that much, the brightness problem was also present there), I'm pretty sure it's a hardware problem and the igpu thing fits in the narrative.

If you know some thing that helps me, or invalidates my claims, I'm more than happy to hear them. Even a single word for a clue that I can do more research on may be of great help.

---

Previous answer:
It didn't fix my problem, but there was a bug ([here][1], [here][2]) that is fixed in 545.29.06. Be sure to update your drivers and see if it help. I'll add more details and accept this answer when I find something that works for me.